# pass the attributes of objects that are found in one lists to other list

Tags: python, list

I happen to be working on a project in which, depending on what the client needs, I create a number of objects (of a class), then these are saved in a list, then the attributes of the objects created must be saved in another list in order to print them in a txt file. I have been able to create several objects and save them in one list, but I cannot access the attributes they have and save them in another list.

Creation of the objects:

```
list_obj = [] 
for i in range (10):
    obj = sensorUltrasonido("verde", 0, 3)
    list_obj.append(obj)
```

Now, the question is how can I save the attributes of those 10 objects created in another list or access them?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Do you mean the arguments you passed to the constructor, or the objects' attributes?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I understand that, but what I don't know is how to access the objects' arguments to save them in another list. Any ideas?

Comment: You have 10 identical objects (unless there is some randomness in the constructor)...

Comment: apologize, it's not arguments, it's the attributes of the objects as you mention

Comment: well you access attributes by doing `obj.attribute`. Did you try that? If you want **all** attributes you can use `vars(obj)`. And again, I don't see the point as you simply have 10 identical objects

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean by "attributes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a second list and simply *append* the attributes to it, which are accessed by calling `dir(obj)`. We will ignore the private attributes by not including those starting with "_". For example:

```
list_obj = []  
list_attrs = []
for i in range (10):
    obj = sensorUltrasonido("verde", 0, 3)
    list_obj.append(obj)
    attrs = [attr for attr in dir(obj) if not str(attr).startswith("_")]
    list_attrs.append(attrs)
```

Afterwards, you can use your lists to write to a text file.

Note that instead of storing two lists full of `[obj, ...]` and `[attrs, ...]`, a variant would be to have a single list of `[(obj, attrs), ...]` because then the relation between those elements is clearer.

Now if you need to store the attributes names and values, we will use a dictionary instead like so:

```
attrs = {attr: getattr(obj, attr) for attr in dir(obj) if not str(attr).startswith("_")}
```

For testing I create a class:

```
class sensorUltrasonido():
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

and `print(list_attrs)` gives us:

```
[{'x': 'verde', 'y': 0, 'z': 3}, {'x': 'verde', 'y': 0, 'z': 3}, {'x': 'verde', 'y': 0, 'z': 3}, {'x': 'verde', 'y': 0, 'z': 3}, {'x': 'verde', 'y': 0, 'z': 3}, {'x': 'verde', 'y': 0, 'z': 3}, {'x': 'verde', 'y': 0, 'z': 3}, {'x': 'verde', 'y': 0, 'z': 3}, {'x': 'verde', 'y': 0, 'z': 3}, {'x': 'verde', 'y': 0, 'z': 3}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I've been testing your solution and it works just as you said. Now, I'm going to try to understand the dictionary part, thanks again

Comment: Glad to help! The dictionary is a container of key-value pairs, for example `{"color": "verde"}` is a dict. Here, we are getting the names of the attributes thanks to `dir(obj)`, the value of a specific attribute via `getattr(obj, attr)`, and the pair is formed by following the `key: value` writing convention.

Comment: Thanks again, one more question, if I wanted you to make a line break every time you show an attribute like:
{'x': 'red' (line break), 
'y': 0 line break, 
'z': 3 line break} 
Where should I put the line break?

Comment: For writing to a file/printing? You can use `"\n.join(f"{key}: {value}" for key, value in attrs.items)"` which adds a line break after each string. You can read about `join` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), it's a handy tool.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Objects to map the parameters in a class. Better go with Magic methods. called **dict** which will return the dictionary of parameters in the object. which can be used to get the required parameter

```
class MyClass(object):
    class_var = 1

    def __init__(self, i_var):
        self.i_var = i_var

foo = MyClass(2)
bar = MyClass(3)

print MyClass.__dict__
print foo.__dict__
print bar.__dict__
```

output would be

```
{'__module__': '__main__', 'class_var': 1, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'MyClass' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>, '__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x0000000004E55CF8>}
{'i_var': 2}
{'i_var': 3}
```

Hope the output might help

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll try to understand the code to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure entirely what you mean but going off of your wording I will suggest the following. Each object can have a list variable in its init function

```
class foo:
  def __init__(self, *args):

     self.argument_list = []
     for items in *args:
        self.argument_list.append(items)
```

So all the data passed into your arguments can be saved to a list for your object.
Then when you create a new object you can always append that to a global list

```
object_arguments = []

F = Foo(Args)
object_arguments.append(F)
```

To access the arguments of an object in that array its as simple as saying

```
object_arguments.argument_list[]
```

Then for a file you can do the following

```
file = open("arguments.txt","w")


for items in object_arguments:
  
     file.write(items.argument_list)

file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I'm going to look at the code and try to understand it, the truth is that I've been with python for two days and I'm missing a lot of things. The bad writing is because I'm not a native english speaker, sorry for the bad writing

Comment: No need to worry :) Everybody on this site is willing to help, any time is a good time to learn programming, I wish you luck on your programming journey!